# How to keep firing bullets in QT game

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

my question is how to keep firing bullets in my game. I can fire 1 bullet and then I get the message QGraphicsScene::addItem: item has already been added to this scene. I have read a few posts on similar topic, however the explanation did not solve my problem. Here is my code snippets. I understand that the item is already added, but how to get around this and keep shooting bullets? Any help or example code would be greatly appreciated.

```
void LevelOne::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
    if (event->isAutoRepeat())
            return;

    switch (event->key()) {

    case Qt::Key_F:     
       addItem(bullet);          // Add the bullet
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Space:     

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}


void LevelOne::initPlayField() {

    bullet = new Bullet() ;
    bullet->setPos(m_player->pos().x(),  m_player->pos().y()
}
```

Comment: If you know the bullets have finite lifetime, and there's some maximum number of bullets, you can pre-allocate so many of them (LevelOne field `Bullet bullets[MAX_BULLETS];` would work probably, with some `std::bitset<MAX_BULLETS> firedBullets;`), and then re-use the spare ones from the array for firing. The answer bellow requires you to delete the bullet after it is done with all, which will put some pressure on dynamic memory management (lot of small Bullet-size fragments of memory being allocated and freed often). Not a problem with simple game, but in AAA titles that would be problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand is that you want to throw bullets when you press the F key, every bullet is new, so you must create that object every time.

```
void LevelOne::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
    if (event->isAutoRepeat())
            return;

    switch (event->key()) {

    case Qt::Key_F:
       Bullet *obj = new Bullet();
       obj->setPos(m_player->pos().x(),  m_player->pos().y()
       addItem(obj);          // Add the bullet
       break;
    case Qt::Key_Space:     

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```